# PHP print_r adds a '1' to the end

Tags: php, arrays

CODE

```
$vArray = array();
foreach( $videos as $video ): 
    $vArray[] = get_field( "article_video_id", $video->ID );
endforeach; 

echo '----';
echo print_r($vArray);
echo '-----';
```

I always get a '1' at the end e.g.

```
-----Array
(
    [0] => Gb6JRborcOU
    [1] => Xi0S2xKXSzg
    [2] => ZGzup1LR9NU
)
1-----
```

Any idea?

Comment: 1 is because it prints result of print_r($vArray) which is 1(Means it get executed successfully)  You can remove echo no need of it

Comment: It does if you echo, yes..... print _r generates output __and__ returns a true, which echo then echoes

Comment: 5 hours too late today: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32733008/3933332

Comment: I think this question already asked today many times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `print_r` echos the output anyway, so you're basically saying `echo echo $vArray`

You can do the following so that it's returned instead of echo'd:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($vArray, true) . '</pre>';
```